# How to add multiple yAxis to nvd3?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, nvd3.js

How can I get such a coordinate arrangement?[image]

writing:

```
y1Axis: {
    axisLabel: 'Тест 1',
    axisLabelDistance: -10,
    orient: 'left',
},
y2Axis: {
    axisLabel: 'Тест 2',
    axisLabelDistance: -10,
    orient: 'left',
},
y3Axis: {
    axisLabel: 'Тест 3',
    axisLabelDistance: -10,
},
y4Axis: {
    axisLabel: 'Тест 4',
    axisLabelDistance: -10,
}
```

I get only two y-axis, and not four, and I want everyone to be on the left:[image]

Comment: Do you really want to do that? 4 axes looks incredibly confusing and bad practice from a data viz perspective. I suggest you break it out into small multiples instead of combining disparate data on one chart.